# Add a new Redistributables to VS InstallShield LE Project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield-le

i want to add `Microsoft SQL CE 4.0` to my VS InstallShield LE Project Redistributables

I've done this steps:

- i'm create a **Microsoft SQL CE 4.0.prq** file(modify it like Microsoft SQL CE
  3.5 SP2.prq) and **Microsoft SQL CE 4.0** folder in this path : `C:\Program Files
  (x86)\InstallShield\2012SpringLE\SetupPrerequisites`
- i copy the **SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.exe** and **SSCERuntime_x64-ENU.exe** in Microsoft SQL CE 4.0 folder

and Result:

[image: VS InstallShield LE Project Redistributables]

The project was built successfully, But the installer can't install SQL CE 4.0..

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

InstallShield Limited Edition doesn't have the Prereq editor found in Professional and Premier.  I assume this means you edited the PRQ XML by hand.  If so, how were you able to make out the schema? There is no XSD and some of the fields are integers that would be meaningless without the tool to help you work it out.

Here's an old blog article showing how to use the tool:

http://blog.iswix.com/2006/11/using-installshield-12-to-install-net.html

If it was me, I'd download an Eval copy of Professional or Premier and throw it on a VM.  Use the tool to edit the PRQ and then copy it back to your LE installation.  Also there is another stack overflow answer where someone said they wrote their own PRQ and posted the code.

[SQL CE 4.0 as a InstallShield Prerequisite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181157/sql-ce-4-0-as-a-installshield-prerequisite)

The fact that it builds tells you all the various files were found.  The fact that it doesn't install means there is something wrong with your XML.

Comment: i followed @chris to solve my issue in including Adobe ActiveX as Prerequiste.