# Visual Studio 2010: Add Microsoft SQL CE 3.5 SP2 to InstallShield Prerequisites

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, installshield, installshield-2010

I try to create an InstallShield for my application in Visual Studio 2010

**The application requires**

> Microsoft SQL CE 3.5 SP2 (x64)

and

> Microsoft SQL CE 3.5 SP2

**So in the InstallShield Prerequisites I checkted the two packages**

[image: Prerequisites]

**If I build my solution, I get many errors concerning to japanese.prq and Windows Server 2003 SP1**

[image: Error]

I checked additionally Windows Installer 3.1 (x86) in InstallShield Prerequisites, but without any effect.

**So I searches in the InstallShield Path**

[image: Windows 3.1]

It seems to be there, but how to fix the build errors?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The snapshot displays that you are using Installshield Limited Edition and the Redistributable or prerequisite editor feature is not available there.

Please refer to the following the URL for more info:
[Add a new Redistributables to VS InstallShield LE Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677056/add-a-new-redistributables-to-vs-installshield-le-project)