# How to include both versions of SQL Server CE 4.0 Runtime in Install Shield wizard

Tags: c#, .net, windows, installation, installshield

I need to include both versions of SQL Server CE 4.0 Runtime in my install shield setup application so the user can use the same version of an installer on both system architectures (x86 and x64).

I found a good solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10224981/382011

But this requires to create two diffrent installers for x86 and x64. In my case I need to combine those two into one setup. How can I modify PRQ files from example to achive it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a single bundled installer, that installs the correct package based on the machine architecture. To do this is quite easy using [Burn from Wix](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2009/7/14/lets-talk-about-burn), the [following SO thread has an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147498/how-to-deploy-64-bit-and-a-32-bit-windows-installer-package-as-a-single-setup/15985524#15985524).

After that you can create a single prerequisite file that installs the bundle.

The installation of the corespondent SQL Server CE prerequisite will be handled automatically by the bundle, so you will separate this logic from the main installer.